# Importing a submodule

Tags: javascript, webpack, import, module

I'm developping a JS library and use webpack to distribute it.
Here is its structure :

```
src
--> index.js
----> foo
--------> index.js
```

Here is `src/index.js` content :

```
export * from './foo'
```

Here is `src/foo/index.js` content :

```
export const bar = () => { console.log('foobar loaded') }
```

I use a basic webpack configuration which relies on the entry :

```
entry: [__dirname + '/src/index.js']
```

It compiles fine and when I import the `foo` module through the `bar` function it works :

```
import { bar } from 'myfoobarlib'
bar()
```

What I want is importing directly from the submodule. 
**This doesn't work** :

```
import { bar } from 'myfoobarlib/foo'
bar()
```

But by adding the `src` in the path (which I don't want), it works :

```
   import { bar } from 'myfoobarlib/src/foo'
    bar()
```

**Question** : How can I import a submodule without putting the `src` string in the import ?

Comment: Unrelated, but please see the bottom of [What are tags, and how should we use them](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging); putting explicit tags in the title is redundant.